# Apply hyperlink to image

Tags: asp.net, css, image, hyperlink

```css
.displayed1
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 275px;
    right: 341px;
}
```

```html
<img class="displayed1" src="Images/NewProjectCohesive02.jpg" alt="" />
```

How can I add a hyperlink of `AddnewPage1.aspx` to the image? Is it necessary for the image to be in a `<form id="form1" runat="server">` tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrap it in an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="AddnewPage1.aspx">
    <img class="displayed1" src="Images/NewProjectCohesive02.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Modifying the CSS won't be necessary, except to remove the border if you prefer (and most do). Also, given that this appears to be an important navigation link, please be sure to provide `alt`-text in the name of accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <asp:HyperLink ID="hpr1" runat="server">
<img  src="img/bg-breadcrumbs-homebtn.png" />
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

(Using Asp.net)

I have done something like

```
<a href='<%#AdUr(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title"), DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"AdId"))%>'>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' runat="server" class="img-responsive" title='<%# Eval("Title")%>'/>
</a>
```

> Remember, use single quotes for Evals.